# Changing icons brakes everything in hera

Tags: system, icons, release-hera

Every time i change the icons in hera everything just crashes i can reboot because there is no panel nor any shortcut works. I have to erase the icon folder from the terminal to be able to reboot and make the system work

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I'm having the same issues. Did you ever manage to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

What method are you using to change the icons? I recommend using Elementary Tweaks https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks